# What is the distribution of this Random Variable? I am expecting a Chi-Squared, but there is one term which is extra

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, chi-squared-distribution, distribution-identification

I am trying to find the distribution o random variable $H$, but I am somehow confused.

The assumption is $M$ and $N$ are large enough (maybe around $100$).

When $L=1$, the distribution of $H$ is a Chi-squared with degrees of freedom of $2$. When $L>1$, I am expecting the same distribution ($2L$), but I do not know how to remove the second term (The summation of cosine terms). Can I assume that because $M$ and $N$ are large enough and the term is divided by $MN$, we can say this term is zero?

Random Variables $\phi_l$ and $\theta_l$ are uniformly distributed over $[0,2\pi]$ and complex coefficients $\alpha_l$ are assumed to be $\mathcal{CN}(0,1)$.

Also, $j=\sqrt{-1}$ and $\beta$ is a real constant number.

$H=\frac{1}{NML}\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left|\sum_{l=0}^{L-1}\alpha_le^{j\beta\left(m\sin(\phi_l)-n\sin(\theta_l)\right)}\right|^2$

When $L>1$, I get this:

$H=\frac{1}{L}\ \sum_{l=0}^{L-1}|\alpha_l|^2+\frac{2}{MNL}\left(\sum_{l'=l+1}^{L-1}\sum_{l=0}^{L-1}|\alpha_l||\alpha_{l'}|\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}cos(\psi_{mn}^{ll'})\right)$

where $\alpha_l=|\alpha_l|e^{j\mu_l}$
and

$\psi_{mn}^{ll'}=\beta \left[q\left( sin(\phi_{ij}^{tl})-sin(\phi_{ij}^tl')\right)-p\left(sin(\phi_{ij}^{rl})-sin(\phi_{ij}^{rl'})\right)\right]+\mu_l-\mu_{l'}$

Comment: This question got a negative point, which I do detest, but I would agree with any criticism **that this is not an easy question to grasp**.

Comment: I already wonder about one of the first statements *"H is a Chi-squared with degrees of freedom of 2MN"*. How is this possible? ...when the *variables* are just $\theta_l$ and $\phi_l$ giving only $2l$ degrees of freedom at least in terms of number of free parameters?

Comment: @Martin Don't forget the $L$ complex variables $\alpha_l.$  That gives $4L$ (real) random variables *in toto.*  Your point still stands, though, unless $4L=2MN.$

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Thanks for your reply. I was trying to simplify the problem, so I made a typo. What I was meant, was $2L$ degrees of freedom. I edited the post. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: What can you tell us about $j$ and $\beta$?  Unless their product is purely imaginary, it's difficult to see how $H$ could possibly have any kind of chi-squared distribution.

Comment: @whuber $j= \sqrt(-1)$ and $beta$ is a constant number.

Comment: I edited the post. I think now it is clear. I wonder if you could unhold the topic. Thabks a lot

Comment: Unless $\beta$ is real, you won't get a chi-squared distribution.  When it is real, you can immediately eliminate the exponential factors because they have unit modulus.  That leaves you with the average of a sum of squares of $|\alpha_l|,$ which (by definition) will be $1/L$ times a $\chi^2(2L)$ variable. If $\beta$ is not real, the problem becomes much messier, so it's crucial to clarify this point.

Comment: $\beta$ is a real value. But we cannot eliminate the exponential factors, because there's a summation of exponential factors, so we cannot eliminate the exponential parts.

Comment: You're right--somehow every time I looked at the formula I saw all summations *outside* the absolute values.